# Why is this true? $\cos\left(\left(n+ \frac{1}{2}\right)\pi\right)=\cos\left(\frac{1}{2} \pi\right) = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, trigonometry

> Why is the following true?
>   $$
> \cos\left(\left(n+ \frac{1}{2}\right)\pi\right)=\cos\left(\frac{1}{2} \pi\right) = 0
> $$

Comment: $\cos(x+\pi)=-\cos x$

Comment: Thanks a lot but... why?

Comment: Have a look a the trigonometric circle.

Comment: What's your definition of the cosine function?

Comment: Because $\pi$ is half-way around the circle.

Comment: Addition formula for cos. $\cos((n+\frac12)\pi) = \cos(n\pi)\cos(\frac12\pi)-\sin(n\pi)\sin(\frac12\pi) = 0$ since $\cos(\frac12\pi)=0$ and $\sin(n\pi)$ = 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $\cos(\pi+x)=-\cos(x)$. If $\cos(\pi/2)=0$, then $\cos(\pi/2+\pi)=-0=0$, $\cos(\pi/2+2\pi)=\cos(\pi/2)=0$. For the last one I've used the periodicity of the cosine function. All the rest of the terms you get from periodicity as well.

Answer (score 0):

Because introducing the value $n$ shifts the cosine function by a multiple of $\pi$. Since the cosine function has a zero at $\frac{\pi}{2}$, and zeros occur every $\pi$ units, this means that your expression is always $0$.